# What does it mean when CNAME record's value is itself?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I'm interested in learning more about the CNAME record's value when it's the same as itself and how it's stored in files. I've been through several CNAME tutorials and overviews, but I haven't found any information that addresses this specific use case. I'm hoping to gain a better understanding of this concept and any insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

In my work VPN, `dig foo.employer.com`, gives me, after the question, this answer:

```
; ANSWER SECTION:
foo.employer.com. 600 IN        CNAME  foo.employer.com.
```

I would appreciate your input in verifying whether this particular CNAME has been orphaned during various migrations or not. If it has not been abandoned, I will appreciate any guidance you can provide about it. I could not find any publicly available CNAMEs similar to this, and it has been modeled on one that I found within my employer's network.

Comment: But as far as I can see it's not an obvious illegal construction to have `foo.example.com. 600 IN        CNAME  foo.example.com.` ; at least [`named-checkzone`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkzone) accepts it and doesn't b0rk. It doens't make much logical sense though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper setup for CNAME should be like this:

```
foo.employer.com. 600 IN CNAME different.domain.com.
```

that is the normal behaviour and it should not point to itself. I recommend taking a second look at the DNS configuration for good measure.

Comment: Not necessarily a different “domain” but rather a different canonical name or “FQDN” and not itself.

Comment: This makes sense. In the normal CNAME examples I find at work, the `different.domain.com.` names generally then have an A record to an IP address. Or multiple A records.

Comment: if you have A-Record then using name to create a alias but creating a loop is courios and looks more like a mistake